# why result not same in postgresql and text editor?

Tags: php, postgresql, phalcon

I have query in postgresql and get result, but when implement to text editor I get error like this :

> Syntax error, unexpected token (, near to 'SelOrdersdetil d INNER JOIN SelOrders p USING (o_kode)) INNER JOIN SelMmenu m USING(sel_mmenu_id) GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan LIMIT 30', when parsing: SELECT d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan, sum(d.od_qty) AS qty, sum(d.od_jmlhrg) AS nominal FROM (SelOrdersdetil d INNER JOIN SelOrders p USING (o_kode)) INNER JOIN SelMmenu m USING(sel_mmenu_id) GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan LIMIT 30 (269)

how to I fixed, I using phalcon and this my code:

```
 SELECT d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan, sum(d.od_qty) AS qty, 
sum(d.od_jmlhrg) AS nominal FROM (sel_ordersdetil d
 INNER JOIN sel_orders p USING (o_kode))`
INNER JOIN sel_mmenu m USING(sel_mmenu_id)  
GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan LIMIT 30
```

thaks

Comment: I assume the stray backtick is a typo.

Comment: no, I am just use backtick in here.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need parentheses in the `FROM` clause:

```
SELECT d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan, sum(d.od_qty) AS qty, 
       sum(d.od_jmlhrg) AS nominal
FROM sel_ordersdetil d INNER JOIN
     sel_orders p
     USING (o_kode) INNER JOIN
     sel_mmenu m
     USING (sel_mmenu_id)  
GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan
LIMIT 30;
```

To be honest, though, I would expect the query to work with the parentheses.

Also, using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is dangerous.  You should include an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: yes, I already gone the parentheses but error and diferrent error,

Comment: Syntax error, unexpected token USING, near to ' (o_kode) INNER JOIN sel_mmenu m USING (sel_mmenu_id) GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan LIMIT 30', when parsing: SELECT d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan, sum(d.od_qty) AS qty, sum(d.od_jmlhrg) AS nominal FROM sel_ordersdetil d INNER JOIN sel_orders p USING (o_kode) INNER JOIN sel_mmenu m USING (sel_mmenu_id) GROUP BY d.sel_mmenu_id, m.nama, m.olahan LIMIT 30 (292)

Comment: @jazuli_18 . . . Postgres has supporting `using` since at least version 8.0 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: Yea but PHQL != postgresql, it doesn't have 1:1 syntax.